# How to grant temporary access to custom content provider using FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider

I am trying to query custom content provider(App A) from another app(App B).

I can do that when there is no permission protection for content provider. Specifically, I build custom content provider on App A and sent an intent containing the URI to App B.
Here is intent-sending part in App A.

```
class InsertOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{        
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(DataBaseConfiguation.TableConfiguation.USER_NAME, "Jack");
            Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(DataBaseConfiguation.TableConfiguation.CONTENT_URI, values);
            System.out.println("uri------------------->" + uri);
            // the uri above should be like "content://com.catking.contentprovider.MyContentProvider/user"
            Uri uri2 = Uri.parse("content://com.catking.contentprovider.MyContentProvider/user");
              Cursor c = managedQuery(uri2, null, null, null, null);
              String sendvalue = null;
               if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                  do{
                     System.out.println("User name:"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseConfiguation.TableConfiguation.USER_NAME)).toString());               
                     sendvalue = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseConfiguation.TableConfiguation.USER_NAME)).toString();
                  } while (c.moveToNext());
               }
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.web", "com.android.web.Provid");
            sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            sendIntent.putExtra("name", uri2.toString());
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
        }
}
```

followed by manifest file of App A.

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name=".ContentProviderTestActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <provider android:authorities="com.catking.contentprovider.MyContentProvider"
        android:exported="true"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:name="com.catking.contentprovider.MyContentProvider" 
        android:readPermission="android.permission.permRead"
        android:writePermission="android.permission.permWrite" >
    </provider>
</application>
```

Then App B(class Provid) get the URI and query the corresponding data in content provider(using following code).

```
public class Provid extends Activity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 
    String userNameuri;
    if (extras != null) {
        userNameuri = extras.getString("name");
      Uri allTitles = Uri.parse(userNameuri);
      Cursor c = managedQuery(allTitles, null, null, null, null);
       if (c.moveToFirst()) {
          do{
             System.out.println("Name is"+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DataBaseConfiguation.TableConfiguation.USER_NAME)).toString());               
          } while (c.moveToNext());
       }
    }
}
```

}

Here's App B's manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:name="._GetWebResoureActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" >
            </action>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver android:name="StaticReceiver11" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MYSEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="Provid"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_provid" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
</application>
```

However, when I query content provider from App B, errors occur:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo {com.android.web/com.android.web.Provid}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening     provider com.ck.contentprovider.MyContentProvider from ProcessRecord{426c6ea8 17032:com.android.web/u0a95} (pid=17032, uid=10095) requires android.permission.permRead or android.permission.permWrite
```

It seems that App B did not make use of the temporary permission to access. In other word, how to utilize FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION from App B?

I have also tried directly adding Uri to intent(using setData()), instead of Uri.toString()(using putExtra()).

```
sendIntent.setData(uri2);
```

and

```
Uri userNameuri = getIntent().getData();
```

But the "userNameuri" got in App B is null.

I am totally confused...

**updated**

I tried "grantUriPermission("com.android.getCPaccess", uri2, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)" according to a previous post
[What is the correct permission handling when sending sensitive app data as email attachment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179594/what-is-the-correct-permission-handling-when-sending-sensitive-app-data-as-email)

And it works indeed. It can work without using FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION. But the permission is not "temporary". It have to be ended manually by revokeUriPermission().

So, I am wondering if there is a way to grant temporary permission as introduced in FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION, or it's a bug at all?

Comment: Is there a <uses-permission> for **android.permission.permRead** in your app that implements the provider & picker activity?

Comment: Hi, Jens. I have also tried that. When both of apps have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.permRead" /> in manifest file, it works fine. But this is the kind of permanent permission.
I want to work out temporary access permission with FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION(as described by google android developer). So the App B won't have android.permission.permRead, instead, it receive the intent with FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION flag "true" from App A. But this fails.

Comment: You should only need one `uses-permission`, declared in the app that declares the picker activity that calls `#addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)`. You should probably include more of your manifest & code in the question.

Comment: Sure. I edited the question. Yes App A doesn't need uses-permission.  But App B shouldn't have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.permRead" />either, because if it has, there's no need to addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION).

Comment: No - application A, which defines the provider, _should_ also define the permission(s) you use for read/write. It **must** also declare a uses-permission for both the read (& write, if you in the future wish to grant write permission also) - you can't grant a permission you yourself do not hold.

Comment: It still cannot work. The weird thing is: if I use putExtra("name", uri2.toString()) to transfer the URI, it may fail because the system may not bundle temporary acecss grant to a string. So I use setData(uri2), but when I use getIntent().getData() on the other side, it shows uri is null. Other part of intent can all be successfully received.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` affects only `Uri Intent.mData` but not uris in extras.

I found similar problems when playing with `ACTION_SEND`, which takes an uri in `EXTRA_STREAM`. Providing the same uri in `setData()` will work, but doesn't conform to the rules and leads to unexpected behavior (e.g. Gmail recipient).

As of Jelly Bean intents can contain ClipData, which should solve the problem. For `ACTION_SEND` it's generated automatically from extras.

`grantUriPermission` will work, but requires `revokeUriPermission`. To do the same job as `startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, title))` you will have to pick the target (`ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY`), grant permissions to its package and revoke them when not needed anymore (onActivityResult?).

Here's some code:

Receiver app:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.handler" >

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        …
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

ActivityView.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if ((intent != null)) {
        procUri(intent.getData());
        procUri(intent.<Uri>getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM));
    }
}

private void procUri(Uri uri) {
    if (uri != null) {
        InputStream i;
        try {
            i = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            byte[] b = new byte[i.available()];
            i.read(b);
            …
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            …
        }
    }
}
```

Sender app:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.sender" >

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" >
        …
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivitySend"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <provider
            android:name=".MyContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.example.sender.content"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true" >
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

ActivitySend.java:

```
// OK!
private void doTestView(Uri uri, String type) {
    startActivity(
            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .setDataAndType(uri, type)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)
                .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
        );
}

// error prior to JellyBean
// ok on JellyBean, even without explicit FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION (due to generated ClipData)
private void doTestSend(Uri uri, String type, CharSequence title) {
    startActivity(
            Intent.createChooser(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                    .setType(type)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                ,
                title
            )
        );
}

// working but not ok, unexpected results!
private void doTestSend2(Uri uri, String type, CharSequence title) {
    startActivity(
            Intent.createChooser(
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                    .setDataAndType(uri, type)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
                    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
                ,
                title
            )
        );
}
```