# Android Nexus 4 give error like java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Deniad

Tags: android, android-gallery, picasa

Only issue with Android Nexus 4, OS 4.2

Getting images from Media Gallery using content path give error in only nexus 4.

**Content Path like this :** `content://com.google.android.gallery3d.provider/picasa/item/itemID`

**Error :**

```
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider
com.android.gallery3d.provider.GalleryProvider from ProcessRecord{658fa748 
4598:com.backlotauctions/u0a739} (pid=4598, uid=10739) requires 
com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER or 
com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER
```

**My Code is:**

```
InputStream is = null;
is = mActivity.getContentResolver().openInputStream(Uri.parse(ImagePath));
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
os.close();
```

This error occurred while **content Resolver** **openInputStream()** using image path.

Comment: Where did you get this `Uri` from?

Comment: This uri get from Media Gallery while select image using intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
     startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE);

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558177/security-exception-when-trying-to-access-a-picasa-image-on-device-running-4-2

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gallery3d.permission.GALLERY_PROVIDER"/>

it's mentioned there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18587967/securityexception-when-downloading-images-with-the-universal-image-downloader

Comment: I already go through this post but not getting solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem a while ago. see my question here

[Security Exception when trying to access a Picasa image on device running 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13558177/security-exception-when-trying-to-access-a-picasa-image-on-device-running-4-2)

It seems you cannot hold onto the uri of picasa images and just pull the image from the uri everytime, you can only use the uri once.

basically what I ended up doing was saving the image locally the first time and use that uri for the image

Comment: This Error occurred in Nexus 4 any other device which got this type of error?

Comment: I check with Samsung Galaxy S4 with OS 4.4.2 but this error not occurred in S4.

Comment: I get the error on any device when I choose the photos app to get pictures and not the gallery app